# Custom post types with their own permalink structure

Tags: categories, url-rewriting

My main posts are news items (category "news"). Therefore, I used global URI writing in the following format: `/year/month/post-name`

I also have posts that contain photo albums (category "photo") but I want these to have another URI structure, namely: `/category/post-name` in which category is `photos`

I've been looking over the Internet and I found [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) (has category, but I think [in category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) is better) that contains quite some information. I also vaguely remember a hook in functions.php that could do this:

```
'rewrite' => ...
```

Unfortunately, for a Wordpress Newbee as myself, it's not enough. I can't figure out how to do this. Any help? Thanks.

So, if the category is news => `/year/month/post-name` e.g. `/2012/10/test-post`
If other category, such as photos or videos => `/category/[sub-category/)post-name` e.g. `/photos/(2012/)France` or for videos: `/videos/(2011/)concert-u2`

### EDIT: the comments tell me that it is wiser to use custom post-types.

I have done that. So far I have two custom post types (`videos` and `photos`). I don't think that there will be any other. What needs to happen: change the permalink structure of the custom post-types. I want them to be `/photos/post-name` and `/videos/post-name`. The regular posts should be `/year/month/post-name`. I added this to my functions.php

```
/* Add custom post-type (fotos) (added by Bram Vanroy) */

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_foto' );

function register_cpt_foto() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'fotos', 'foto' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'foto', 'foto' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Nieuw fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Voeg nieuw fotoalbum toe', 'foto' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Bewerk fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nieuw fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Bekijk fotoalbum', 'foto' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Zoek in fotoalbums', 'foto' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Geen fotoalbums gevonden', 'foto' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Geen fotoalbums gevonden in de prullenmand', 'foto' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent foto:', 'foto' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Foto\'s', 'foto' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Het posttype dat alle foto-albums verzorgt.',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,


        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );

    register_post_type( 'foto', $args );
}

/* Add custom post-type (videos) (added by Bram Vanroy) */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_video' );

function register_cpt_video() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'videos', 'video' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'video', 'video' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Voeg nieuwe video toe', 'video' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Voeg nieuwe video toe', 'video' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Bewerk video', 'video' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nieuwe video', 'video' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Bekijk video', 'video' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Zoek video\'s', 'video' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Geen video\'s gevonden', 'video' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Geen video\'s gevonden in de prullenmand', 'video' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent video:', 'video' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Video\'s', 'video' ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => 'Dit posttype wordt gebruikt om filmpjes te publiceren',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'page-category' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,


        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'page'
    );

    register_post_type( 'video', $args );
}
```

And I suppose I need some rewrite rules here, but I don't know how to!

Comment: So what do you want the URLs to look like?

Comment: this would be much simpler if you just created a custom "photo" post type and separated them from normal posts.

Comment: @MihaRekar Look at my edit.

Comment: @Milo I tried custom post types, but this didn't seem to work well with the parent theme I use. But, let's say I would use a custom type: can you give a specific answer on this post which states how to create a custom post type and how to change the urls accordingly?

Comment: Look into [WordPress Custom Post Type Code Generator](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/)

Comment: @MihaRekar Okay, I did that (what a useful tool)! But what do I do know?

Comment: you've since edited your question to add a whole other layer of complexity with the addition of videos and year subcategory, so the answer to this has changed. you have the option again of adding yet another custom type for videos, but the question is, do you want to have an open ended number of categories that assume this differing pattern, or will they be fixed? the other part to the equation is outputting URLs to the template. if you have a URL format that doesn't follow default structure, you need to filter the output of URLs to match the incoming patterns.

Comment: @Milo I was trying to add more detailled information, but apparently that didn't really help? I have edited the post, I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself (with you guys' help): It was easy as anything:

```
'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'videos',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
```